# Predefining one element of a row matrix where other elements are created via an equation

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that is created via the equation

```
for xxx = 1 : xMid_p - 2
   ln_p(1,xxx) = abs(radius_p(1,1) - radius_p(xxx+1));
end
```

However I need this equation to have zero as its first element. I understand I can do this via

```
ln_p(1,1) = 0;
```

But how do I combine this so as that the first element is zero and the rest of the row matrix is taken from the equation above.

---

Solution:

It was pretty simple and involved concatenating a simple 1x1 matrix with the ln_p matrix.

```
lnZero(1,1) = 0

for xxx = 1 : xMid_p - 2
   ln_p(1,xxx) = abs(radius_p(1,1) - radius_p(xxx+1));
end 

ln_p = horzcat(lnZero,ln_p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirty trick maybe; use this inside the loop -

```
ln_p(1,xxx) = (xxx~=1).*(abs(radius_p(1,1) - radius_p(xxx+1)));
```

Comment: This sets the initial first value to 0 i.e. the former first value is no longer in the array. For clarity say ln_p = 1,2,3,4,5 I want to be able to recreate it so it is ln_p = 0,1,2,3,4,5. i.e. so as that the row array contains one extra element which happens to be 0 regardless of the equation and comes at the beginning of the array

Comment: You want to set the first value - `ln_p(1,1)` to be zero, overwriting the previous first value in it. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @user3454983 Ah gotch ya!

Comment: @user3454983 And you don't want to concatenate after the loop ends? It would be easier that way.

Comment: ahhh never even thought of that, it wouldn't be an issue to concatenate. The above is part of a larger loop but I can simply nest another loop within it

Comment: Exactly! Just do `ln_p = [0 ln_p];` after this loop ends, simple enough!

Answer (score 0):

Just use vectorized indexing and simple horizontal concatenation:

```
ln_p(1, 1:xMid_p-1) = [0  abs(radius_p(1)-radius_p(2:xMid_p-1))];
```

if your `ln_p` is empty before the loop and `radius_p` is exactly `xMid_p-1` elements long, you can simplify this to:

```
ln_p = [0  abs(radius_p-radius_p(1))];
```